# Ubuntu 18.04 and bonding

Tags: network-bonding

[image][image]

Is there any good walkthroughs on how to get bonding working on 18.04?

I have a server with two interfaces currently set as DHCP and would like to have bonding setup for resilience

I know I could do it while installing 18.04 but I want to learn how to do it by command line. As far as im aware this has to be done using netplan?

Comment: Through netplan, correct. I'm not very familiar at all with bonding, but there are example yaml files available; for example: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan.io/examples/bonding.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I decided to reinstall ubuntu and setup networking bonding using the install so I could get an idea of what it would like but Im having issues now.

on the screenshot you can see the configuration I have in place and have set the dhcp 4 as true and I get an ip address but i cannot ping out or ping the gateway. 

not sure what the issue is

Comment: I got this working by adding the bridged as you can see in the 2nd screen shot added to this.

Comment: I don't fully understand why it needs a bridge to work though

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please format your post in a proper way - use plain text instead of images!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason bond don't work if don't have the Link Monitoring in the netplan config. Just add--> mii-monitor-interval: 100 under mode: active-backup let me know if that helps thanks.